# How can i position an <article> right beside another <article> so that I can have them horizontally?

Tags: css, html

I've encountered a problem where I need to put two different `<article>`s on the same line or horizontally aligned, with the FirstArticle on the left with its width and the SecondArticle on the right of the FirstArticle with its own width.

```css
.MainContent {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.Content {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 48%;
}

.FirstArticle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.SecondArticle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContent">
    <div class="Content">
        <article class="FirstArticle">
            <header class="Header">
                <h2>First Article</h2>
            </header>
            <footer class="Footer">
                <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
                </p>
            </footer>
            <content>
                <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!)
                    looking on We
     As only a sort of They!</p></q>
            </content>
        </article>
        <article class="SecondArticle">
            <header class="2Header">
                <h2>Second Article</h2>
            </header>
            <footer class="Footer">
                <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
                </p>
            </footer>
            <content>
                <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!) looking 
                    on We
     As only a sort of They!</p></q>
            </content>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not closing your tags properly. `<p><q>` need to be closed with `</q></p>`. You close the most recently opened tag first.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `float` on the articles (not on their container) and limiting their width:

The essential code boils down to this (there is more is the snippet below):

```
.Content {
  width: 96%;
}
.FirstArticle, .SecondArticle {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
}
```

```css
.MainContent {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.Content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  width: 96%;
}
.FirstArticle {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
}
.SecondArticle {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContent">
  <div class="Content">
    <article class="FirstArticle">

      <header class="Header">
        <h2>First Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="Footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!)
                    looking on We
     As only a sort of They!</q>
        </p>
      </content>

    </article>

    <article class="SecondArticle">

      <header class="2Header">
        <h2>Second Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="Footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!) looking 
                    on We
     As only a sort of They!</p></q>
      </content>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give both article a

`float:left`

after that you give them a specific width for instance

`width:100px`.

So they look like this:

```
.FirstArticle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.SecondArticle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex.

check this snippet

```css
.MainContent {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContent">
  <div class="Content">
    <article class="FirstArticle">

      <header class="Header">
        <h2>First Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="Footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>
      <content>
        <p>
          <q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!)
                    looking on We
     As only a sort of They!</q>
        </p>
      </content>

    </article>

    <article class="SecondArticle">

      <header class="2Header">
        <h2>Second Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="Footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!) looking 
                    on We
     As only a sort of They!</q>
        </p>
      </content>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using `flexbox`:

Define a flex-container using `display: flex;` in your `.content` class.

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

This will make every direct children a flex-item, in this case your `article` elements. Use `flex: 1;` in this elements to fill all the available space within the flex-container.

```
.first-article {
  flex: 1;
}
.second-article {
  flex: 1;
}
```

or

```
.content article{
  flex: 1;
}
```

> `flex: <positive-number>` Equivalent to `flex: <positive-number> 1 0`.
>   Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.

---

### Code Snippet:

```css
.main-content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  width: 48%;
  display: flex;
}
.first-article {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}
.second-article {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="content">
    <article class="first-article">

      <header class="header">
        <h2>First Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>
      <section>
        <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!)
                    looking on We
     As only a sort of They!</q>
        </p>
      </section>

    </article>

    <article class="second-article">

      <header class="second-header">
        <h2>Second Article</h2>
      </header>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p class="post-info">some text for the footer..
        </p>
      </footer>

      <section>
        <p><q>All good people agree,
     And all good people say,
     All nice people, like Us, are We
     And every one else is They:
     But if you cross over the sea,
     Instead of over the way,
     You may end by (think of it!) looking 
                    on We
     As only a sort of They!</q>
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Notes:

- Do not use the `<content>` element, it is deprecated, reference **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content)**.
- Be careful with your CSS selectors, even though CSS syntax is case-insensitive, in some browsers this may or may not cause issues. Also your classes cannot start with a number unless you escape it.